# Cómo reestructurar consulta

Tags: php, sql

Me encuentro en duda. ¿Cómo puedo reestructurar esta consulta?

```
$mexico = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM paises WHERE pais = 'MEXICO'");
                $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mexico);
                printf("%d\n", $result["total"]);
                mysqli_free_result($mexico);
```

Mi idea es retirar el **mysqli_query($conexion,**
para que

```
$mexico = ("SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM paises WHERE pais= 'MEXICO'");
```

pero al hacerlo me arroja como resultado **0**

Esperando pronta respuesta.

Gracias

Comment: ¿por qué necesitas retirarlo, es decir cual es el fallo que intentas resolver?

Comment: Si retiras mysqli_query, no ejecutas la consulta, sólo le asignas a $mexico un string con la consulta. ¿Es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: Hola anomino. Necesito concatenarle una condición (otra consulta en el que va solo WHERE) y al ejecutarla asi $mexico = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM paises WHERE pais = 'MEXICO'");
                $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mexico);
                printf("%d\n", $result["total"]);
                mysqli_free_result($mexico); me sigue arrojando en mismo resultado sin la condicion

Comment: y estaba checando unos ejemplo en internet y no tienen esa parte  mysqli_query($conexion y es más facil concatenar

Comment: Alfabravo mi intencion no es eliminar la linea, mi duda es solo si se puede reescribir en otra linea.

Comment: @user11149721 puedes crear el string de la consulta antes, asignadolo a una variable, para posteriormente pasarselo a `mysqli_query()`, es decir primero escribes la consulta y luego la ejecutas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras leer los comentarios, creo que estás equivocando el concepto.

```
$mexico = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM paises WHERE pais = 'MEXICO'");
```

Esta línea de código crea la consulta ("SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM paises WHERE pais = 'MEXICO'") Y LA EJECUTA contra la conexión $conexion con el 'mysqli_query'.

Esto es como hacer una pregunta. Primero construyes la pregunta, luego vas donde la persona a la que quieres hacérsela, y entonces se la comunicas, y él te responde (por eso la parte de '$mexico = ' y la línea '$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mexico);', para saber qué te está respondiendo).

Si haces

```
$mexico = ("SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM paises WHERE pais= 'MEXICO'");
```

lo que estás haciendo es pensar la pregunta y creer que la pregunta es la respuesta. No haces la pregunta, ni siquiera buscas a quién hacérsela.

Si lo que quieres hacer es agregar otra condición, puedes, como te dice @Xerif, prepararte la pregunta de antes:

```
$pregunta = "SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM paises WHERE pais = 'MEXICO'"
--- AQUÍ PUEDES AÑADIR LA CONDICIÓN ---
$mexico = mysqli_query($conexion,$pregunta);
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mexico);
printf("%d\n", $result["total"]);
mysqli_free_result($mexico);
```

Y recuerda que para concatenar condiciones no se ponen varios WHERE, se pone un WHERE, y después AND para cada condición adicional (como si fuera una pregunta normal, no preguntas "¿Cual es el total teniendo en cuenta que (WHERE) el país es México teniendo en cuenta que (WHERE) la empresa es Coca Cola?", preguntas "¿Cual es el total teniendo en cuenta que (WHERE) el país es México y (AND) la empresa es Coca Cola?")